# Why react-native-pell-rich-editor is showing Javascript title while opening linking tag?

Tags: react-native, rich-text-editor

react-native-pell-rich-editor

[image: 1]

I am using react-native-pell-rich-editor while opening linking tag it showing javascript keyword there. Please tell me if you know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because rich editor uses a javascript prompt to display that modal, alternatively you could try to create a custom modal and add it to rich editor add link function (find it on node_modules/react-native-pell-rich-editor/src/editor.js) or you can make a custom action for it

editor.js line 303

```
link: {
  result: function(data) {
    data = data || {};
    var title = data.title;
    title = title || window.getSelection().toString();
    // title = title || window.prompt('Enter the link title');
    var url = data.url || window.prompt('Enter the link URL');
    if (url){
      exec('insertHTML', "<a href='"+ url +"'>"+(title || url)+"</a>");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure ,will give it a try and tell you. Is there any other package that can Provide features like mentioning people and rich text features for react-native ?

Answer (score 1):

etcN00b solution worked in ios and for android create custom URL modal,pass the ref of the editor and make use of **ref.insertLink(null,link)** in your custom method of the modal